Mismatched filter and arbitrary waveform radar range resolution
Books and papers usually define a radar range resolution proportional to the pulse bandwidth inverse:
$\Delta R = \dfrac{c}{2B}$
This seems intuitive when one considers the matched filter mainlobe width for a chirp pulse. However, how can one compute or at least define range resolution limits for an arbitrary mismatched filter or an arbitrary waveform (e.g. a Barker code) ? My understanding is that the only thing we are sure of in such cases is the resulting filter output SNR, which will necessarily be lower than the matched filter SNR (under the additive Gaussian noise hypothesis).
Other than that, neither the range resolution nor the sidelobes have identified limits, and thus are arbitrarily good or bad depending on what (filter, transmitted signal) one picks. This seems supported by old and new papers creating mismatched filters using iterative optimization or machine learning approaches. I'm probably wrong, trying to understand exactly how wrong I am and answer this with equations.

I think you will find that the resolution is still $c/2B$, but that other measures such as ISLR and/or PSLR degrade. Around the mainlobe,  these IPRs are still effectivley $\mathrm{sinc}$ functions.

And the range resolution is not arbitrarily good or bad. Unless you are doing some type of non-linear processing, the best peak-to-null resolution of the IPR will be the reciprocal of the bandwidth.

Thank you for your comments. Can you be more specific regarding "some type of non-linear processing" please ?

MUSIC, SAMV, and other such algorithms (see wikipedia to get started) would be examples of non-linear processing. In terms of forming range profiles, however, their uses are pretty limited. Spatially Variant Apodization is another example of a super-resolution technique and is also one, at least in my experience, that sees a lot of practical use.

I was familiar with MUSIC but not with SVA. I'll look into it thanks :)


However, how can one compute or at least define range resolution limits for an arbitrary mismatched filter or an arbitrary waveform (e.g. a Barker code) ?

You use a stochastic model for your noise, add that, find an ML estimator for range, or use your own estimator and describe it in stochastic terms, then find the standard deviation of range as estimated under that noise.
So, in the end, it's "just" transforming random variables and keeping track of variance.
Empirically, you look at the ambiguity function of the convolution of your transmit and your receive system, and find the marginal distribution (of only range).

Other than that, neither the range resolution nor the sidelobes have identified limits, and thus are arbitrarily good or bad depending on what (filter, transmitted signal) one picks.

Sure. I mean, if you pick a receive filter that has nulls exactly where your signal has energy, then your estimator can estimate nothing.

This seems supported by old and new papers creating mismatched filters

This isn't that surprising. The one thing that a matched filter optimizes in AWGN is the SNR. It doesn't optimize for range certainty.
In effect, you do want the output of the "transmit pulse – pulse shaper – channel – receive filter" system to be as "pulsey" as possible, so the intuitive approach would look more like an equalizer than a matched filter, if you asked me.

Thanks. If I understand correctly your answer confirms it isn't absurd to optimize a mismatched filter to improve the output range resolution for a predetermined input chirp bandwidth as waveform ? Which amounts to look for a mismatched filter with lower SNR but narrower mainlobe, compared to the corresponding matched filter.

@Blupon You will not be able to improve the output resolution this way. A mismatched filter is just a certain time-domain convolution kernel. In the frequency domain, this is just a multiplication of the waveform's and filter's spectrums, and this cannot increase the bandwidth of your data. If you want to improve upon the mainlobe, you would typically use the mismatched filter to condition the spectrum of your waveform to have the ideal $\mathrm{rect}$-like characteristics and then run something like SVA on the output.

Thanks for your intuitive comment. I do appreciate the illustration of spectrums product which suggests "increasing the output bandwidth/resolution with a fancy filter" is absurd, though this seems to contradict the "new" paper linked in my initial question ? E.g. the abstract says "The networks are trained with an objective to return MF outcomes corresponding to a higher bandwidth pulse. ".

no, that's not surprising, "corresponding to a higher bandwidth pulse" doesn't mean much. It says "we're as good as someone with a higher-bandwidth pulse, if they are stupid about their receiver".

Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by "if they are stupid about their receiver" ? I'm afraid I'm still confused.

"The networks are trained with an objective to return MF outcomes corresponding to a higher bandwidth pulse." I don't buy it. You ultimately don't care about the spectrum of your waveform. In an ideal world you would remove it completely upon reception and be left with what you actually care about it, i.e., the spectrum of your target(s). Without knowing what the spectrum of your targets are ahead of time, there is no way to train a network to extrapolate out that information.

@AnonSubmitter85 thing is, targets do have a stochastic distribution of shapes; you can sure adapt to that (again, that's just an equalizer in the end)

If you want to try to convince someone that you can transmit a waveform with $B$ (Hz) of bandwidth, put the reflection through a network and get out $2B$ (Hz) of spectrum on an unknown arbitrary target, all I can say is good luck to you.

nah, not that. But that's also not what I wrote.

Apologies if I misunderstood your comment, but that is what the paper he links is claiming.

Yes, precisely, thanks for confirming it's probably wrong (or misunderstood). I'll look into the formalization of an arbitrary waveform range resolution with an ML estimator as suggested by Marcus and accept the answer to close the current question. Thanks again !

The result of a waveform's resolution being inversely proportional to its bandwidth is "quite" general, in the sense that it applies to virtually all types of practical waveforms used in radar systems.
With the matched-filter, the only guarantee that you get is that it maximizes the output SNR in the presence of AWGN. Improving the range resolution by applying modulation is a secondary benefit.
Considering a simple unmodulated pulse, the range resolution it can achieve can be intuitively understood in the time domain. In order for two targets to be distinguishable, they cannot overlap in time, and this is achieved if they are at least a pulse width $\tau$ apart. No need for a matched filter here: you can do this by some other reception and filtering methods and still get both targets. Once the separation is less than $\tau$, the signals combine and this is no longer as easy to do, or even possible depending on certain conditions.
Introducing the matched filter, the output of a simple rectangular pulse is a triangle function, which due to the correlation, is actually $2\tau$ wide. If you have two targets that are exactly $\tau$ apart, the composite output of the matched filter is a flat-topped trapezoid. Once the targets depart by more than $\tau$, the trapezoid now has a dip, and you can technically resolve both targets by their peaks, although not as reliably if the SNR is low. Despite this, we still say that the range resolution of the waveform is $c\tau/2$. The Rayleigh bandwidth $\beta$ of a rectangular pulse of length $\tau$ is  $\beta= \ 1/\tau$, and thus the expression for the range resolution being $c/(2\beta)$ appears.
So what's the deal with $c/(2\beta)$ defining the resolution for a given waveform? In a noiseless environment, the matched filter implements the autocorrelation $R_{xx}(\tau)$ of the transmitted waveform $x(t)$. Practical waveforms usually meet the conditions to apply the Wiener-Khinchin theorem that states that the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function is the power (or energy depending) spectral density $S_{xx}(f)$ of $x(t)$:
$$ \mathcal{F}(R_{xx}(\tau)) = S_{xx}(f)= |X(f)|^2$$
When analyzing a waveform, you're dealing with this Fourier transform pair. I'm not going to go into too much rigor, but the influence on $\beta$ on the range resolution is related to the frequency-time duality of signals. There's the tendency for short signals in time having large bandwidths and vice-versa. Looking at the transform pair above, it should be intuitive that putting more bandwidth into $x(t)$, which yields a wider $|X(f)|^2$, should shorten $R_{xx}(\tau)$ in time.
Many of the matched-filter responses of common radar waveforms are sincs or sinc-like, primarily being composed of a mainlobe and decaying sidelobes (or constant sidelobes in the case for Barker codes, for example). If you look at the spectrums of these waveforms and consider their Rayleigh bandwidths, you will see that they they correspond to equivalent "compressed pulse widths" $\tau_c = 1/\beta$. Depending on the waveform, the range resolution $c/(2\beta)$ is approximate, but usually good enough. To better see what the performance of a waveform is, you should construct an ambiguity function diagram.
When it comes to mismatched filters, all bets are off. Usually one designs these to control sidelobes, at the expense of the mainlobe increasing in width (degraded resolution) and a lower maximum achieved SNR. There are some common mismatched filters for certain waveforms with known trade-offs and their analysis, but in general this is something that must be done by the designer on one's particular case.
I currently can't speak to machine learning approaches, but I would be hard pressed that they can achieve better without some serious restrictions. If you want a more rigorious look at the time-frequency duality and the bound on the time-bandwidth product of a signal, take a look at Dilip's answer here.
